# Zend: Custom View helpers

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I'm trying to add a View helper in my project, but I'm getting the following error:

```
[Mon Apr 29 14:36:19 2013] [error] [client 10.0.0.26] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'LoggedInAs' was not found in the registry; used paths:\nMy_View_Helper_: /var/www/html/test-project/application/views/helpers/\nZend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/html/test-project/application/views/helpers/' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:412\nStack trace:\n#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1182): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('LoggedInAs')\n#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(618): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'loggedInAs')\n#2 /usr/share/php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(344): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('loggedInAs')\n#3 /var/www/html/test-project/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(16): Zend_View_Abstract->__call('loggedInAs', Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/test-project/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(16): Zend_View->loggedInAs()\n#5 /usr/share/php/Zend/View.php(108): include('/var/www/html/t...')\n#6 /usr/share/php/Zend/View/Abstract.php(888): Zend_View->_run('/var/www/html/ in / /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

**application/views/helpers/LoggedInAs.php**

```
class My_View_Helper_LoggedInAs extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function loggedInAs()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

**application/configs/application.ini**

```
resources.view[]=
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

**application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml**

```
echo $this->loggedInAs();
```

There are several other questions on stackoverflow, but these didn't work for me.

**edit 1:**
changed `Zend_View_Helper_LoggedInAs` to `My_View_Helper_LoggedInAs` after Tim Fountain's answer
**edit 2:**
full error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you provided doesn't seem to make much sense, if you are saying you added `<?php` to the top of the file where your class is written, all I can say is "Welcome to PHP!"
otherwise the following may help in the future... or not.

Using the master `application.ini` from [feibeck](https://github.com/feibeck/application.ini/blob/master/application.ini) as a reference, I came up with:

```
//excerpt from application.ini
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
resources.view.helperPathPrefix = "My_View_Helper"
```

however you are using the defaults for the MVC so you shouldn't require any config at all.

This may be a case of too much config.

**That being said:**
I've never been a fan of setting view options in the `application.ini` as I'm never quite sure of what effect I should expect (*am I adding or setting an option?*). I much prefer to setup the view in the bootstrap as most of the methods used are more verbose and tell a more complete story:

```
//bootstrap.php
protected function _initView()
    {
        //Initialize view
        $view = new Zend_View();
        //add custom view helper path
        $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/View/Helper');
        //add custom script path for partials
        $view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/View/Scripts/');
        //set css includes, path is relative to /public
        $view->headlink()->setStylesheet('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');
        //add javascript files, path is relative to /public
        $view->headScript()->setFile('/bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js');
        $view->headScript()->appendFile('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        //add it to the view renderer
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
                'ViewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);
        //Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
        return $view;
    }
```

Hope this provides some help.

Comment: Yes I know, stupid that I didn't think of it. I'm already coding in PHP for a couple of years now, but I'm quite confused now I'm learning ZF ;)

Comment: Don't let ZF confuse you to0 much, It's just PHP. (hint hint) :)

Answer (score 0):

The class name should be `My_View_Helper_LoggedInAs`, since that's what you declared as your namespace in application.ini. The Zend namespace is only for ZF classes.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error? It should also list the paths and namespaces it tried

Comment: Okay, well everything that you've posted looks fine to be honest. Can you double check that the filename of the class is indeed LoggedInAs.php (case sensitive)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a strange solution, since I can't find anything like this on internet.
I just added `<?PHP` at the beginning of **application/views/helpers/LoggedInAs.php**